# Why there are two ConsumerConnector declarations?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

there are two definitions of ConsumerConnector:
a) kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector
b) kafka.consumer.ConsumerConnector​

Could anyone please help me explain the differences? Thanks!

Also, if I use ConsumerConnector to get KafkaStream, where will the consumer offset be kept? Because when I create ConsumerConnector it still ask me to provide zookeeper url.

Comment: Isn't a the java one, and b the scala version ?

Comment: @Nicholas Yes, you are right. Thanks!